# Installing node takes up to 8 minutes

Tags: node.js, macos, homebrew, macos-high-sierra

I am on the latest High Sierra build.

When I am installing an npm (node), it takes up to 8 minutes to install...

```
  /usr/local/Cellar/node/8.5.0: 4,152 files, 47.8MB, built in 7 minutes 51 seconds
```

Is this normal behaviour?

Comment: Why don't you use the official Node.js installer (https://nodejs.org/en/)?

Comment: Because i am using homebrew for more than node, some missing programs etc.

Comment: I use Homebrew as well, but _also_ use the official Node.js installer. The Homebrew-installed Node.js can cause all kinds of issues (judging by the amount of questions being posted here on StackOverflow). FWIW, it's probably taking that much time because it's being compiled from source, instead of being a binary install.

Answer (score 1):

It is not normal. I should take longer if you're building from the sources and shorter if you're installing the binary packages. See the install options at:

- https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Also you can see this tutorial on installing Node using any type of those packages (binary and source) with exact commands that you need to run:

- https://gist.github.com/rsp/edf756a05b10f25ee305cc98a161876a

I never recommend installing a programming language runtime (Node, Python, Ruby, Perl etc.) with anything other than official packages because it can cause all sorts of problems. Those runtimes have their own package manager s that you should use to install modules and libraries and using something else for that can cause hard to track problems and is usually not worth the hassle. The only tool that I can recommend here is `nvm` because I've read its source code and I know what it's doing, though I would never run the recommended way of piping the `curl` output straight to `bash` without seeing what I downloaded first.

Comment: I was building it form source, so it was fast i think?